# What are Layout Filters?

Tags: layout, filter

Website: http://thegrid.io talks about something called "Layout Filters" which are more powerful than "templates"

So what are they? I tried googling but nothing came up. And how are they more "powerful" than "templates"?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the marketing terminology used by a product on its own marketing website rather than a broader, more general phrase.

Answer (score 2):

Usually CMS has template pages, that user has to populate with content. Regular CMS prioritises page templates instead of content on the other hand The Grid prioritises content and then makes smart page templates/layouts that can evolve. This is good for the user because user doesn't have to rely on the programer to make new page templates for new types of content. For the web... not sure I think it might lead to old MySpace type of pages, the only thing that probably stopping it is the cost involved.

Take a look at the article on [Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/sites/anthonykosner/2014/10/15/the-grid-website-platform-automatically-adapts-design-to-make-your-content-shine/) and [CMS critic article](http://www.cmscritic.com/the-grid-artificial-intelligence-meets-web-design-or-does-it/)

> "layout filters” (as The Grid calls its version of content management “themes”)

Comment: Yeah, I have never used The Grid, so maybe someone will be able to explain it better.

Comment: Its not public yet. But its a good concept.